# Choosing Children but not grandchildren with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, children

I have a nested unordered list like so:

```
<ul id="parent">
   <li>
      <ul> <!-- select this-->
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   <li>
</ul>
```

I need to select the children of #parent but not the grandchildren.

`$(#parent).children('ul');` selects all children, including grandchildren. How do I limit this to just children?

Comment: Your question is not clear. the ul in question IS a grandchild of #parent. That's why the answers you are getting will not work. Also, you are missing a </ul> at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#parent').children('>ul');
```

The above would not work with the markup in the question.

You want the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

You'd need the following:

```
$('#parent > li > ul');
```

Answer (score 2):

Children method should do the trick. Are you sure you're getting grandchildren?. You selector should actually return 0.

This code should do what you're looking for

```
$('#parent>li').children('ul')
```

From [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .children() method allows us to search through the children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. **The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.)**

Answer (score 1):

put `>` before `ul`;

```
$('#parent').children('>ul');
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your original selector: `$('#parent > li > ul')`