# Selecting items with children but not grandchildren using jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I am trying to select list items that have children, but not list items that are grandchildren. Consider the following structure:

```
<ul id="parent">
   <li>
      <a href="#"></a>
      <ul> <!-- add open class -->
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <ul>  <!-- do not add any class -->
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   <li>
</ul>
```

I hide all children lists like so:

```
#parent li > ul {display:none}
```

When I hover over any top-level list item, I would like to add a class to its child `<ul>` but NOT its grandchild `<ul>`. So in the tree above I wrote the `<ul>` that needs a class added.

The following selects all list items with  children:

```
$("#parent li:has(ul)").hoverIntent( showSubNav, hideSubNav );
```

I need this to ONLY select the top level list items that HAVE children but I do not want this function to trigger when I hover over grandchildren list items that also have children.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: $("#parent > li:has(ul)").hoverIntent(showSubNav, hideSubNav); :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing Children but not grandchildren with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195883/choosing-children-but-not-grandchildren-with-jquery)

Comment: @r3bel, this also selects the grandchildren li because they also have ul children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a descendent selector.

```
$("#parent > li:has(ul)").hoverIntent( showSubNav, hideSubNav );
```

This will only do `$.hoverIntent()` on immediate children `li`s that have a child `ul`.

If you want to show the adjacent `ul` when you hover over the `<a>`, then this:

```
$('#parent > li > a').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').addClass();
});
```

Hovering over a top level `<li>` and then add a class to it's immediate `<ul>` child:

```
$('#parent > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).child('ul').addClass();
});
```

Comment: the problem is that there are anchors after each li. See updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Having the anchors won't mess up the selector, though. Do you want to add the class when you hover over the anchor instead?

Comment: no when I hover over the list item, add class to its closest ul down in the tree. But this only applies to children, not grandchildren

Answer (score 0):

would this work?

```
//find the first UL in #parent
$('#parent').find('ul').first().each(function(){
    //check if the first UL has any children
    if($(this).find('ul').length > 0){
        //this ul has children UL
    }
    else{
        //this does not have children UL
    }
});
```